# Swift: Open message controller for second time

Tags: ios, swift, sms, message

whenever the user presses on a logo, a counter will count from 0 to 3. after these 3 seconds, I am presenting the message controller for the user:

```
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
            print(self.urgentNumber)
            let recipients:[String] = ["\(self.urgentNumber as! String)"]
            self.messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self as? 
            MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
            self.messageController.recipients = recipients
            self.messageController.body = "Hey,\nmy longitude: \
            (self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude) \nmy latitude: \
            (self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"

            self.present(self.messageController, animated: true, 
                completion: nil)


    } else {
        //handle text messaging not available

    }
```

when the user presses cancel or send the message, I am detecting this in :

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    messageController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

here the user should wait 20 sec to send another message:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20, execute: {
        self.reSetAnimations()
    })
```

The problem is, When the user presses on the logo the second time( After waiting the 20 sec to give him the ability to press again), the message controller is not opening again!

any idea why?

Comment: What does `reSetAnimations` do?

Comment: nothing other than removing some animation that runs when the user presses for 3 sec. plus hiding a view that covers the page for a 20 sec to prevent the user from interacting with this page.

Comment: So where do you call your code to present the `MFMessageComposeViewController` again?

Comment: timerDidEnd(), When the timer finish counting till 3

Comment: Does your `timerDidEnd()` get called? Did you try putting breakpoint?

Comment: yes it is being called and the message code above is being re-entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new instance of the `MFMessageComposeViewController` instead of reusing the old one.

Comment: I was declaring 

        let messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()

outside the timerDidEnd(). when I declared it in the method, it solved my problem.